# app = Application().start("machine.exe") returns error: (0, 'WaitForInputIdle', 'No error message is available')

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am trying to automate a windows GUI machine.exe using pywinauto. I used the command `app = Application().start("machine.exe")` which throws this error after opening the machine.exe GUI
`error: (0, 'WaitForInputIdle', 'No error message is available') in line 901 of application.py`. I would like to understand the cause of the error message

I have tried to start the Gui using os.startfile and then connect to the gui using connect ()method
I am using python 2.6.6, OS is windows 7

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

def test():
    app = Application().start("machine.exe")
    app.connect(title="machine.exe")
```

I expected it to just open the gui without any issues.

Comment: Is this Windows 7 machine locked? Maybe Remote Desktop window is minimized? (if you're there remotely)